# Read Email from Gmail inbox as it arrives

Tags: php, drupal, imap

I've a drupal 7 site, and requires a functionality by which I can read emails from gmail inbox whenever they arrives. Currently I'm achieving it with php imap by running it on cron.

But I want something, which can read email from inbox as soon as it arrives.

Please suggest, thanks

Comment: Maybe PHP isn't the right tool?

Comment: Have you checked Google API? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/ "Typical use cases - Read-only mail extraction"

Answer (score 0):

This would be a bit of a round-the-houses approach but create an account with mailgun.com. Within Mailgun you can then direct incoming emails to a URL you specify. Mailgun parses the email and sends it to you in a structured format.

You could then set up your Gmail account to send a copy of all incoming emails to your Mailgun account.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. I'll try to implement this in my code. Just wondering, if they Mailgun can do this, they must be using some Google API. I'll try to search it too and will post answer here.

Comment: I believe they wrote the algorithm themselves. They were bought by Rackspace but recently spun off again into a private company.  Anyway, good luck